# How to track an error from the "journalctl -u NetworkManager"?

Tags: logs, networkmanager

I'm having sudden disconnections from the network, while doing nothing.

My system information:

```
Kubuntu 19.04
Wireless Adapter:  TP-LINK TL-WN781ND v2.2 (Default driver is named Qualcomm Atheros A9485, I don't know if it's normal)
```

`journalctl -u NetworkManager` log after a crash:

```
nov. 14 09:26:54 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720014.1554] manager: startup complete
nov. 14 09:26:56 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720016.4040] policy: auto-activating connection 'Siouffi' (e7f9423e-ce30-4852-ac6a-8623089c3dd3)
nov. 14 09:26:56 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720016.4043] device (wlp3s0): Activation: starting connection 'Siouffi' (e7f9423e-ce30-4852-ac6a-8623089c3dd3)
nov. 14 09:26:56 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720016.4044] device (wlp3s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov. 14 09:26:56 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720016.4045] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
nov. 14 09:26:56 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720016.4047] device (wlp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov. 14 09:26:56 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720016.4049] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'Siouffi' has security, but secrets are required.
nov. 14 09:26:56 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720016.4049] device (wlp3s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov. 14 09:26:56 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <warn>  [1573720016.4052] device (wlp3s0): no secrets: No agents were available for this request.
nov. 14 09:26:56 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720016.4052] device (wlp3s0): state change: need-auth -> failed (reason 'no-secrets', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov. 14 09:26:56 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720016.4054] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
nov. 14 09:26:56 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <warn>  [1573720016.4055] device (wlp3s0): Activation: failed for connection 'Siouffi'
nov. 14 09:26:56 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720016.4056] device (wlp3s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov. 14 09:26:57 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720017.2692] policy: auto-activating connection 'FreeWifi' (90f42afe-df0c-446a-a424-3624ecd0b612)
nov. 14 09:26:57 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720017.2695] device (wlp3s0): Activation: starting connection 'FreeWifi' (90f42afe-df0c-446a-a424-3624ecd0b612)
nov. 14 09:26:57 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720017.2696] device (wlp3s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov. 14 09:26:57 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720017.2698] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
nov. 14 09:26:57 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720017.2699] device (wlp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov. 14 09:26:57 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720017.2701] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'FreeWifi' requires no security.  No secrets needed.
nov. 14 09:26:57 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720017.2701] Config: added 'ssid' value 'FreeWifi'
nov. 14 09:26:57 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720017.2701] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
nov. 14 09:26:57 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720017.2701] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-80:86400'
nov. 14 09:26:57 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720017.2701] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'NONE'
nov. 14 09:26:57 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720017.2920] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: ready -> authenticating
nov. 14 09:26:57 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720017.2920] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: ready -> authenticating
nov. 14 09:26:57 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720017.2990] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
nov. 14 09:26:57 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720017.2990] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
nov. 14 09:26:57 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720017.3123] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> completed
nov. 14 09:26:57 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720017.3123] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network "FreeWifi"
nov. 14 09:26:57 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720017.3123] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> completed
nov. 14 09:26:57 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720017.3125] device (wlp3s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov. 14 09:26:57 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720017.3149] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
nov. 14 09:26:57 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720017.3201] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): dhclient started with pid 1399
nov. 14 09:26:57 orionss-desktop dhclient[1399]: DHCPDISCOVER on wlp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x62a4dc26)
nov. 14 09:26:57 orionss-desktop dhclient[1399]: DHCPOFFER of 10.58.73.125 from 10.63.255.253
nov. 14 09:26:57 orionss-desktop dhclient[1399]: DHCPREQUEST for 10.58.73.125 on wlp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x26dca462)
nov. 14 09:26:57 orionss-desktop dhclient[1399]: DHCPACK of 10.58.73.125 from 10.63.255.253 (xid=0x62a4dc26)
nov. 14 09:26:57 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720017.6258] dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   address 10.58.73.125
nov. 14 09:26:57 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720017.6258] dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   plen 13 (255.248.0.0)
nov. 14 09:26:57 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720017.6258] dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   gateway 10.63.255.254
nov. 14 09:26:57 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720017.6258] dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   lease time 3600
nov. 14 09:26:57 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720017.6258] dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   nameserver '212.27.40.241'
nov. 14 09:26:57 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720017.6258] dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   nameserver '212.27.40.240'
nov. 14 09:26:57 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720017.6258] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): state changed unknown -> bound
nov. 14 09:26:57 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720017.6265] device (wlp3s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov. 14 09:26:57 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720017.6269] device (wlp3s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov. 14 09:26:57 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720017.6270] device (wlp3s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov. 14 09:26:57 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720017.6272] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
nov. 14 09:26:57 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720017.6542] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
nov. 14 09:26:57 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720017.6544] policy: set 'FreeWifi' (wlp3s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
nov. 14 09:26:57 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720017.6548] device (wlp3s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
nov. 14 09:26:57 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720017.6552] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
nov. 14 09:26:57 orionss-desktop dhclient[1399]: bound to 10.58.73.125 -- renewal in 1399 seconds.
nov. 14 09:27:01 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720021.2881] agent-manager: req[0x562fc619cc00, :1.57/org.kde.plasma.networkmanagement/1000]: agent registered
nov. 14 09:27:14 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720034.4146] audit: op="statistics" arg="refresh-rate-ms" pid=1369 uid=1000 result="success"
nov. 14 09:27:20 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720040.4676] device (wlp3s0): disconnecting for new activation request.
nov. 14 09:27:20 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720040.4676] device (wlp3s0): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'new-activation', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov. 14 09:27:20 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720040.4678] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTING
nov. 14 09:27:20 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720040.4739] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="e7f9423e-ce30-4852-ac6a-8623089c3dd3" name="Siouffi" pid=1369 uid=1000 result="success"
nov. 14 09:27:20 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720040.4741] device (wlp3s0): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'new-activation', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov. 14 09:27:20 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720040.4910] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 1399
nov. 14 09:27:20 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720040.4910] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): state changed bound -> done
nov. 14 09:27:20 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720040.4932] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
nov. 14 09:27:20 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720040.4935] device (wlp3s0): Activation: starting connection 'Siouffi' (e7f9423e-ce30-4852-ac6a-8623089c3dd3)
nov. 14 09:27:20 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720040.4943] device (wlp3s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov. 14 09:27:20 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720040.4945] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
nov. 14 09:27:20 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720040.4947] device (wlp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov. 14 09:27:20 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720040.7015] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'Siouffi' has security, but secrets are required.
nov. 14 09:27:20 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720040.7016] device (wlp3s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov. 14 09:27:20 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <warn>  [1573720040.7094] sup-iface[0x562fc60cd130,wlp3s0]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
nov. 14 09:27:20 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720040.7154] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
nov. 14 09:27:20 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720040.7154] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: completed -> disconnected
nov. 14 09:27:20 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720040.7270] audit: op="statistics" arg="refresh-rate-ms" pid=1369 uid=1000 result="success"
nov. 14 09:27:20 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720040.7515] device (wlp3s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov. 14 09:27:20 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720040.7518] device (wlp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov. 14 09:27:20 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720040.7520] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'Siouffi' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
nov. 14 09:27:20 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720040.7520] Config: added 'ssid' value 'Siouffi'
nov. 14 09:27:20 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720040.7520] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
nov. 14 09:27:20 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720040.7520] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-80:86400'
nov. 14 09:27:20 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720040.7521] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'
nov. 14 09:27:20 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720040.7521] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
nov. 14 09:27:20 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720040.7521] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
nov. 14 09:27:20 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720040.7641] audit: op="statistics" arg="refresh-rate-ms" pid=1369 uid=1000 result="success"
nov. 14 09:27:20 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720040.7790] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> authenticating
nov. 14 09:27:20 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720040.7791] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> authenticating
nov. 14 09:27:20 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720040.7905] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
nov. 14 09:27:20 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720040.7905] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
nov. 14 09:27:20 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720040.7980] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
nov. 14 09:27:20 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720040.7981] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
nov. 14 09:27:20 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720040.8483] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
nov. 14 09:27:20 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720040.8483] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network "Siouffi"
nov. 14 09:27:20 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720040.8483] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
nov. 14 09:27:20 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720040.8486] device (wlp3s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov. 14 09:27:20 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720040.8488] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
nov. 14 09:27:20 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720040.8507] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): dhclient started with pid 2272
nov. 14 09:27:20 orionss-desktop dhclient[2272]: DHCPDISCOVER on wlp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0xaef6f834)
nov. 14 09:27:20 orionss-desktop dhclient[2272]: DHCPOFFER of 192.168.0.48 from 192.168.0.254
nov. 14 09:27:20 orionss-desktop dhclient[2272]: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.0.48 on wlp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x34f8f6ae)
nov. 14 09:27:22 orionss-desktop dhclient[2272]: DHCPACK of 192.168.0.48 from 192.168.0.254 (xid=0xaef6f834)
nov. 14 09:27:22 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720042.9131] dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   address 192.168.0.48
nov. 14 09:27:22 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720042.9131] dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   plen 24 (255.255.255.0)
nov. 14 09:27:22 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720042.9131] dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   gateway 192.168.0.254
nov. 14 09:27:22 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720042.9132] dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   lease time 43200
nov. 14 09:27:22 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720042.9132] dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   nameserver '192.168.0.254'
nov. 14 09:27:22 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720042.9132] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): state changed unknown -> bound
nov. 14 09:27:22 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720042.9137] device (wlp3s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov. 14 09:27:22 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720042.9142] device (wlp3s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov. 14 09:27:22 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720042.9148] device (wlp3s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
nov. 14 09:27:22 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720042.9154] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
nov. 14 09:27:22 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720042.9252] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
nov. 14 09:27:22 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720042.9253] policy: set 'Siouffi' (wlp3s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
nov. 14 09:27:22 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720042.9255] policy: set 'Siouffi' (wlp3s0) as default for IPv6 routing and DNS
nov. 14 09:27:22 orionss-desktop dhclient[2272]: bound to 192.168.0.48 -- renewal in 18165 seconds.
nov. 14 09:27:22 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720042.9258] device (wlp3s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
nov. 14 09:27:22 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720042.9262] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
nov. 14 09:27:23 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573720043.0306] audit: op="statistics" arg="refresh-rate-ms" pid=1369 uid=1000 result="success"
nov. 14 08:27:38 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573716458.9971] audit: op="statistics" arg="refresh-rate-ms" pid=1369 uid=1000 result="success"
nov. 14 08:39:05 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <warn>  [1573717145.1118] sup-iface[0x562fc60cd130,wlp3s0]: connection disconnected (reason -4)
nov. 14 08:39:05 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573717145.1298] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
nov. 14 08:39:05 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573717145.1299] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: completed -> disconnected
nov. 14 08:39:05 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573717145.2199] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
nov. 14 08:39:05 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573717145.2200] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
nov. 14 08:39:06 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573717146.0864] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
nov. 14 08:39:06 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573717146.0864] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
nov. 14 08:39:06 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573717146.0983] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
nov. 14 08:39:06 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573717146.0984] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
nov. 14 08:39:06 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573717146.1088] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
nov. 14 08:39:06 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573717146.1100] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
nov. 14 08:39:07 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573717147.1158] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
nov. 14 08:39:07 orionss-desktop NetworkManager[868]: <info>  [1573717147.1168] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
```

I would like to resolve my problem but moreover, I would like to be able to solve these kind of problems, and know where to search.

Thanks for your help, if you need more information, please be kind, I don't know all the information you can need.

Answer (score 0):

You could enable `level=TRACE` logging in NetworkManager.conf.

But in this case, it looks like the disconnect comes from wpa_supplicant, so better (also) enable debug logging of supplicant. I usually just edit `wpa_supplicant.service`, pass `-ddd` to supplicant and restart the service. But there could be better ways do achieve this.